# How do I use 2 different version of same gem in same application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to use two different versions of gem in same Rails Application. Not in same file but application. How to do that?

Comment: Could you give an example why you want to do that?

Comment: I am using spreadsheet and databasedotcom gem. Both require oauth but former require version 0.5.1 and later requires 0.2.0.

Comment: Sorry, this won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try forking and patching one of the gems to use newer version of oAuth, and then use the patched version of the gem in you app.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'patched-gem', :git => 'git@github.com:youraccount/patched-gem.git'
```

I am not sure if the patched gem would simply work with the newer version of oAuth though.